# Setting content in a different frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, frames

I have a page I have to update, it has 3 frames (top bar, side bar and main content. If i click something in the main content frame i want to update a list in the side bar frame. how do i do this (i use jquery or javascript for button clicks).

Comment: is using frames mandatory? they should and could be avoided imo.

Comment: I tried Divs but then i have issues with the position:absolute, so i tried tables and had even worse issues getting all the styles to apply, so to save me time im just going to use the frames they gave me

Comment: Maybe a good idea is to use a frame for the top bar as this has allot of content i dnt have time to re-write and then make the side bar and main content tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the name of your frame in the target of your a-tag.

```
<a href="example.html" target="your-frame-name">yourlink</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest, based on my understanding of your layout. You have one window with three frames in it. Also, you are using jQuery.

When you are in one iframe and need to talk to another iframe, use the second parameter on the jQuery selector to set the scope of your selector back to the main window. You would do that as follows:

```
$("iframe[name=myframe]", window.opener.document).contents().doWhatever()
```

If you do this on all of your selectors that need to talk back and forth, then you should be fine. I have used this before, and it works.